# Failing to use PGO with error LNK1270

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, pgo

I'm trying to use Profile Guided Optimization (PGO) with VS8. After instrumenting the DLL in question I copy it over to a machine that has our application installed and run the training scenario. I then copy the **pgc** training files back to my dev box and get the following error:

> 1>StdAfx.obj : fatal error LNK1270: invalid file; timestamp does not match file linked with /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bwby8h5.aspx) entry for this error says:

> invalid file; timestamp does not match file linked with /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT
>   The same files passed to the linker when specifying /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT must also be passed when specifying /LTCG:PGOPTIMIZE.
>
> /LTCG:PGOPTIMIZE requires that the inputs be identical to the /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT phase.
>
> To resolve this warning, run /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT, redo all test runs, and run /LTCG:PGOPTIMIZE, or, create the optimized image with /LTCG:PGUPDATE instead of /LTCG:PGOPTIMIZE.

Rerunning the tests doesn't solve the problem (although it sometimes appears for other files, not stdafx.obj).

Using `/LTCG:PGUPDATE` *does* work however I would like to understand what is causing the error, or failing that are there any drawbacks to using `PGUPDATE` rather than `PGOPTIMIZE` (I can't find anything relevant in the [MSDN PGO page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k.aspx)).